# Make an opamp go rail-to-rail on a voltage higher than opamp supply

Tags: operational-amplifier, mosfet, driver

So I've chosen to work with an High Frequency Opamp that can only use 5V for power (I can't use any other Opamp). But I need the signals to go Rail-to-rail at say, 24V. So naturally I thought I'd just use complementary MOSFETs to amplify this to 24V.

While using Common Source for the complementary MOSFETs does accomplish this, it does invert the output, which have square waves that I can't leave inverted. I can invert it again with a another Common Source complementary, configured to leave gain unity of 1. But is there a more elegant solution?

I considered a Common Drain complementary, though I didn't know what it was called at the time. At that time, I saw MOSFETs as a voltage-controlled resistor, I = g_m * (V_gs - V_th) -- wrong, of course, and the external resistor and the MOSFET, together, are basically voltage dividers. So it follows that, in voltage amplification, it does not matter if I take the output from the Source or Drain side of the MOSFET (after pull-up or before pull-down resistors). But one will be inverted and the other not. Well, it turns out the equation for gate voltage and Drain current isn't that simple, so the "Common Drain" complementary setup won't make it go rail-to-rail.

Is there any other way to make this go rail-to-rail?
(example below has been scaled down to 12V):

EDIT:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feplmy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

-- the biasing resistors are omitted

As for the Opamp, it's a Differential with a gain of 16.5dB. I don't know if one could use negative feedback on this Opamp though.

EDIT 2:

I think you can use a 7V Zener on the opamp's supply ground going to -6V... One would also have to connect the ground of 5V and 6V onto -6V... Or I think one can... If it can work, it'll be noisy, that's for sure, so one might have to do some filtering there. It's a cheap way out, if you only have a 12V supply.

Comment: Show the circuit you used is my advice.

Comment: Common gate is the obvious answer : apply the opamp output to the source, with the gate biassed to an appropriate DC value. But a full range opamp is probably a simpler solution.

Comment: Like I said, I need this specific Opamp.

Comment: Common gate? But doesn't that need a current source?

Comment: I think you will have to justify the statement that you are locked into that particular opamp. There are a plethora of opamps available and it is almost certain that you can find one more suitable to your application than the one you are fixated on.

Comment: Yes. The opamp will be acting as a current source. How much current do you need at the drain? if the opamp can supply that much to the source, you're good. However if you're expecting high bandwidth, you have quite a difficult design problem, but common gate is a good choice for high bandwidth applications.

Comment: @Michael. While I agree with you, it's one of this site's little ironies that if he simply asked for a recommendation with bandwidth xxx and supply range yyy, that would be an off-topic question!

Comment: So, you're trying to deliver several watts of square wave (unspecified frequency, unspecified bandwidth) to ... an (unspecified type of) antenna? There are many potential traps here, including legal ones.

Comment: Why do you need an op-amp in the first place? Can't you design the circuit using only discretes? Are you building a radio transmitter?

Comment: No, show the full circuit not an artist's impression.

Comment: @Brian: I still don't get how a current source will be created. I thought the output of the Opamp goes to the Source of the MOSFET only?

Comment: @Andy: Most of the time, it's better to describe everything in abstract terms, you capture a more generic set of problems. Though, it requires the asker to set the parameters just right, so the answer is decidable.

Comment: That's a euphemism for laziness in my book.

Comment: Are you using the op-amp as a comparator? If you are, why not just use a comparator with open-drain output?

Comment: @Andy: What real laziness is, is doing away with all the other factors and assume things, rather than working with the theoretical framework. By theoretical framework, I mean generality in the right places.

Comment: @DonutCloseDizAccount How about rather than philosophying you start anwsering some questions?

Answer (score 9):

If the only problem is that the amplifier stage you made inverts the signal, just flip the inputs of the opamp around to compensate.

For another approach, use a different opamp, or do the whole thing with discrete parts in the first place.  You said in your first sentence *"I've chosen to work with an High Frequency Opamp that ..."*.  You chose it, you can un-choose it.  You have given no justification for why you need to use this particular opamp, so ditching it remains a valid answer.